# Making one line string

Tags: c#, .net

I need help I have task in c# to make program that take user input (string).You are given the noises made by different animals that you can hear in the dark, evaluate each noise to determine which animal it belongs to. Lions say 'Grr', Tigers say 'Rawr', Snakes say 'Ssss', and Birds say 'Chirp'.

Input Format:
A string that represent the noises that you hear with a space between them.

Output Format:
A string that includes each animal that you hear with a space after each one. (animals can repeat)

I make this

```java
    using System;
    using System.Reflection.Metadata;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    
    namespace nekaVjezba
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    
    
                var text = Console.ReadLine();
    
                var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\w+[^\s]*\w+|\w");
               
    
    
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    var word = match.Value;
    
    
                     if (word == "Grr")
                          {
                        Console.WriteLine("Lion");
    
    
                    }
                          else if (word == "Rawr")
                          {
                        Console.WriteLine("Tiger");
    
                    }
                          else if (word == "Ssss")
                          {
                              Console.WriteLine("Snake");
                          }
                          else if (word == "Chirp")
                          {
                              Console.WriteLine("Bird");
                          }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

That is work but my output is

- Lion
- Lion
- Tiger
- Snake

but it should be in one line
**Lion Lion Tiger Snake**

Comment: Try changing `Console.WriteLine` to `Console.Write` and adding a space after each output (`Console.Write("snake ");`)

Comment: There is also a Console. Write...

Comment: You might also consider creating a `Dictionary<string, string>` that maps noise to animal. And finally, take a look at `string.Split`. In general, if you don't need a Regex, it's a good idea to take the non-regex solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there are many ways to do this. However, here is a succinct solution (to ô̖p̖̝̃̉en̺͔͍͌̍̈́ y̯͇̦͌̍͌oũ̠͍̫̀͡r̜̚ m̠̞͑̍i̭̓ṇ̼̍͘d͈̪͍̑̚͝) using a `Dictionary` and *LINQ*.

Since the words are separated by a space, then a simple `string.Split` would work fine.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
{
   {"Grr", "Lion"},
   {"Rawr", "Tiger"},
   {"Ssss", "Snake"},
   {"Chirp", "Bird"},
};

var animals = Console
   .ReadLine()?
   .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Select(word => !dict.TryGetValue(word, out var animal) ? "N/A" : animal)
   .ToList();

if (animals?.Any() == true)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", animals));
else
   Console.WriteLine("Nothing entered");
```

**Input**

```
grr bob chirp ssss
```

**Output**

```
Lion, N/A, Bird, Snake
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
> that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
> character array.

[Dictionary<TKey,TValue>(IEqualityComparer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__)

> The `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation to use when comparing keys, or
> null to use the default `EqualityComparer<T>` for the type of the key.

[Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, TValue) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netcore-3.1)

> Gets the value associated with the specified key.

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1)

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
> collection, using the specified separator between each element or
> member.

[Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

> Available in C# 6 and later, a null-conditional operator applies a
> member access, ?., or element access, ?[], operation to its operand
> only if that operand evaluates to non-null; otherwise, it returns null

[Language Integrated Query (LINQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

> Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) is the name for a set of technologies
> based on the integration of query capabilities directly into the C#
> language. Traditionally, queries against data are expressed as simple
> strings without type checking at compile time or IntelliSense support.
> Furthermore, you have to learn a different query language for each
> type of data source: SQL databases, XML documents, various Web
> services, and so on. With LINQ, a query is a first-class language
> construct, just like classes, methods, events. You write queries
> against strongly typed collections of objects by using language
> keywords and familiar operators.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to improve this but the simplest advice might be to build a single output string, add to it and write it to the console in a single statement, something like this (semi pseudo code):

```
//Intitialize an output string
var output = "";

foreach(Match match in matches)
//Add to output
If(word== "Grr")
    { outPut += "Lion ";}
      ...
}
//Then after all results are added to the string, print the string
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Write instead of `Console.WriteLine("...")` just `Console.Write("...")`, so you don't write to a new **line**, but on the same line. Then add a space after each word that should be output (`Console.Write("Tiger ");`), as indicated in the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace nekaVjezba
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = Console.ReadLine();
            var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\w+[^\s]*\w+|\w");
           

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
          var word = match.Value;
          if (word == "Grr")
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Lion ");
          }
          else if (word == "Rawr")
          {
            Console.Write("Tiger ");
          }
          else if (word == "Ssss")
          {
            Console.Write("Snake ");
          }
          else if (word == "Chirp")
            Console.Write("Bird ");
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** now can be : *"Lion Lion Tiger Snake"*

Comment: @jvzznjs you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper left of their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things could make this easier to do.

First you don't need a regular expression to parse space delimited input.  So unless that's a requirement you can just use String.Split.

Second you can use either a switch statement or a switch expression to match the input tokens.  And you can break that out into a separate method as well.  Here's an example using a switch expression:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> ToAnimal(IEnumerable<string> sounds)
    {
        foreach (var sound in sounds)
        {
            yield return sound switch
            {
                "Grr" => "Lion",
                "Rawr" => "Tiger",
                "Ssss" => "Snake",
                "Chirp" => "Bird",
                _ => throw new ArgumentException("unknown sound")
            };
        }
    }
```

You can call that using the result from string.Split.  Like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        string RawInput = "Grr Grr Rawr Ssss";

        string[] sounds = RawInput.Split(' ');

        foreach (var animal in ToAnimal(sounds))
        {
            Console.Write(animal);
            Console.Write(' ');
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```

Obviously you'll want to use Console.ReadLine to get the input string.